# Trouble graphing dates on both axes in D3 v4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I've searched around but can't seem too understand my problem with graphing these data in d3. The cx and cy coordinates seem right to me, but all the points are rendering far offscreen.

First I load the array with data (This is being done in angular. I skipped a few lines with the array forEach but this is the part that matters):

```
dataArray.push({
   'x_axis': new Date($scope.thisCompany.acquisition[key].date),
   'y_axis': new Date($scope.thisCompany.acquisition[key].date).getMonth(),
   'radius': '20',
   'color': 'red'
});
```

The data Array ends up coming out like this:

```
[{x_axis: Date 2017-07-16T05:00:00.000Z ,y_axis: 6, radius: '20', color: 'red'}, {x_axis: Date 2017-07-29T05:00:00.000Z ,y_axis: 6, radius: '20', color: 'red'},{x_axis: Date 2003-09-03T05:00:00.000Z ,y_axis: 8, radius: '20', color: 'red'}]
```

finally here is the d3 code.(EDIT) I forgot to add this earlier because I was so tired, but the y axis should be graphing months (Jan, feb etc.) and the x axis should be graphing years (2001 2002 2003):

```
                var foundedOn = new Date($scope.thisCompany.foundedOn);
                const todaysDate = new Date();
                const selectGraph = d3.select('#acquisition-history-chart').append('svg')
                    .attr('width' , '100%')
                    .attr('height' , '100%');
                const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                    .domain([foundedOn , todaysDate])
                    .range([0 , 700]);
                const yScale = d3.scaleTime()
                    .domain([new Date(2012, 11, 31) , new Date(2012, 0, 1)])
                    .range([240 , 0]);
                const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                    .scale(xScale);
                const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"));
                const circles = selectGraph.selectAll('circle')
                    .data(dataArray)
                        .enter()
                        .append('circles');
                const circleAttributes = circles
                    .attr('cx' , function(d) { return xScale(d.x_axis); })
                    .attr('cy' , function(d) { return d.y_axis; })
                    .attr('r' , function(d) { return d.radius; })
                    .style('fill' , function(d) { return d.color; });
                selectGraph.append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(50, 260)')
                    .attr('class' , 'xAxis')
                    .call(xAxis);
                selectGraph.append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(20, 35)')
                    .attr('class' , 'yAxis')
                    .call(yAxis);
```

Here's a JS Fiddle. Couldn't get the graph to display here. Still working on it: https://jsfiddle.net/d3zv8Lon/

Comment: Did you mean `.attr('cy' , function(d) { return yScale(d.y_axis); })`?

Comment: @DWal I figure that's what it should be, but that returns all the cy values as the same number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the yScale domain is between the beginning of 2012 and the end of 2012, then the months in y_axis also need to be in 2012. If they are just months on their own, they will default to 1900.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/xq3oajt3/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <style>
    #company-acquisition-graph {
      width: 100%;
      height: 290px;
      /*background: #1B1B1B;*/
      background: gray;
      border: 1px solid #383838;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
      border-radius: 3px;
      clear: both;
      #acquisition-history-chart {
        border-radius: 3px;
        .xAxis,
        .yAxis {
          path,
          line {
            stroke: #1B1B1B;
          }
          text {
            fill: white;
          }
        }
        .yAxis text {
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-weight: 300;
          text-anchor: start;
        }
        .yAxis g:nth-child(odd) text {
          font-size: 8px;
          stroke: #B9B9B9
        }
        .yAxis g:nth-child(even) text {
          font-size: 11px;
        }
        .xAxis g:nth-child(even) text {
          stroke: #B9B9B9;
        }
      }
    }
  </style>
  <div id="company-acquisition-graph">
    <div style="width:100%; height: 290px;" id="acquisition-history-chart">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var dataArray = [{
      "x_axis": new Date('2017-07-16T05:00:00.000'),
      "y_axis": new Date('2012-06-01'),
      "radius": 20,
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "x_axis": new Date('2017-07-29T05:00:00.000'),
      "y_axis": new Date('2012-06-01'),
      "radius": 20,
      "color": "red"
    }, {
      "x_axis": new Date('2003-09-03T05:00:00.000'),
      "y_axis": new Date('2012-08-01'),
      "radius": 20,
      "color": "red"
    }];

    var foundedOn = new Date(1989, 00, 01);

    const todaysDate = new Date();

    const selectGraph = d3.select('#acquisition-history-chart').append('svg')
      .attr('width', '100%')
      .attr('height', '100%');

    const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([foundedOn, todaysDate])
      .range([0, 700]);

    const yScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([new Date(2012, 11, 31), new Date(2012, 0, 1)])
      .range([240, 0]);

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
      .scale(xScale);

    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(yScale)
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"));

    const circles = selectGraph.selectAll('circle')
      .data(dataArray);

    var newCircles1 = circles.enter();

    newCircles1.append('circle')
      .attr("class", "seeMe")
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return xScale(d.x_axis);
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return yScale(d.y_axis);
      })
      .attr('transform', 'translate(50, 0)')
      .attr('r', function(d) {
        return d.radius;
      })
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return d.color;
      });

    selectGraph.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(50, 260)')
      .attr('class', 'xAxis')
      .call(xAxis);

    selectGraph.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(20, 35)')
      .attr('class', 'yAxis')
      .call(yAxis);
  </script>
```

Also your circles need to be translated a bit right to line up with the x-axis correctly.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any strings to parse?

Comment: Any chance you could set up a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I think you still need to tell d3 how to read 2017-07-16T05:00:00.000Z

Comment: I updated the answer to show the string being parsed.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this before. I'm trying to graph months on the y axis and year in the x axis. Will this still work?

Comment: Currently when I try this, it makes all the cx values the same thing ~-371.8502656233556. I'm trying to work on a fiddle, but having trouble displaying the graph

Comment: Well link to the fiddle anyway

Comment: var foundedOn = new Date(1989); is not the year 1989, but the start of Unix time Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:01 GMT+0000 (GMT)

Comment: Use   var foundedOn = new Date(1989, 00, 01);

Comment: y_axis: 6 gives no indication what year it belongs to and so will default to the year 1900